# Turn radio input and label into clickable url string

Tags: javascript, forms, onclick

Excuse my newbieness. I'm just trying to understand something.

```
<span class="button">
            <input type="radio" id="button-2" name="button-group-1">
            <label onclick="changeButton('2');" for="button-2">Text</label>
        </span>
```

What would the actual clickable link be to the above?

For example, the following url is the same as typing in "stackexchange" in the Google.com search box: https://www.google.com/search?q=stackexchange

How would the same be accomplished with the first example? Thanks.

Comment: Are you saying that your goal is to have clickable links that navigate the user to another URL?

Comment: what are you trying to a achieve ?

Comment: Nothing. I just want to understand this.

Comment: How are the link and the HTML related? Is the input label text meant to be the querystring part of the link?

Comment: I have no idea Andy. I thought the code alone was enough for an html string. Sorry. #iamanewb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't create a clickable "link", it simply creates a `label` (which when clicked) activates the selection of its associated radio button. `<label>` is used for accessibility as it makes it easier to click items on small displays and is read aloud by screen readers.

The `onclick` part is there to invoke a separate JavaScript function called `changeButton` and to pass the string of `'2'` to it. You haven't provided that function, so there's no telling what it does, but it is a separate action from the `label` and the `radio` button.

```js
// Because of the onclick in the HTML of the label, this function will be invoked
// when you click the label and the data of "2" will be passed to it.
function changeButton(input){
  console.log("You invoked the changeButton function and passed it the value of: " + input);
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" id="button-2" name="button-group-1">
<label onclick="changeButton('2');" for="button-2">You can click here or on the radio button to activate the radio button, but you can only click on this text to invoke the onclick event associated with the label.</label>
```

If you want an actual link created, you can simply use the HTML `<a>` element, which is for hyperlinks:

```html
<a href="https://www.google.com/search?q=stackexchange">Search for Stack Exchange</a>
```

Comment: @costumingdiary The label is connected to the element that has an `id` that matches the value of the label's `for` attribute. In this case, the radio button. No information is passed between the `label` and the `radio` button. The `onclick` is doing something completely separate from the native functionality of the HTML.

Comment: @costumingdiary No. you can only "turn" something into something else with JavaScript. HTML is a static language, what you write is what you get. Don't forget to mark this as "the" answer.

Comment: Okay. I thought any input can be turned into a url string if you append the correct queries to it without the need to pass it to a script (like the Google example). I am still confused as to why Google's form can turn into a url by appending the correct labels to it, but the other one can't. Guess it's over my head.

Comment: @costumingdiary Most likely Google's forum has JavaScript that causes that transformation. Don't for get to up vote and mark this as "the" answer to your question.

Comment: Oh. So a string like this from Amazon.com

    https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=dummies+guide+to+javascript

is not an automatic shortcut / transformation of the form. It is really me entering my query, Amazon.com script processing it, and Amazon.com script returning the query as a value to the url bar that I can cut and paste for some reason? Wild.

Comment: @costumingdiary Actually, that is just a URL. There's nothing special about it.It just points to a particular product page. There is no form involved.